# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: .../tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: tomcat9, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I was running Apache Tomcat 9.0.30 until a happy day when I started to see the following message in my IDE output window:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Software\apache-tomcat-9.0.30\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

Note the direction, my hardware is 64-bit, but it does not seem to approve a 32-bit DLL.

(I have deployed a web application at the root `localhost:8083/`.)

One additional symptom is that the Tomcat's default 404 page is presented when I try to access some pages.